# Ember Nested Views in Master Detail UI

Tags: ember.js

I'm trying to create a master/detail UI with Ember that is a little different from the typical scenario shown in most guides/demos I have viewed.  In my case, I want to have a list of users (loaded from /patients) where each user element has its own dedicated detail panel that is populated (with additional details loaded from /patients/:id) and rendered when an element/button is clicked in the master view.  The typical master/detail demo online renders the detail for any element in a list of elements into a single detail element somewhere on the page.

Router:

```
App.Router.map(function() {
    this.resource('patients', function() {
    this.resource('patient', { path: ':patient_id' });
    });
});
```

Models:

```
App.PatientsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
    return this.store.find('patient');
    }
});

App.PatientRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
    return this.store.find('patient', 1);
    }
});
```

Templates:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
    {{outlet}}
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="patients">
{{#each item in model}}
    {{#link-to "patient" item}}show detail{{/link-to}}
    ...info....
    {{outlet}} <--where "patient" detail panel goes
{{/each}}

<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="patient">
    ....detail info....
</script>
```

This retrieves and renders the list of patients.  But, when any detail link is clicked, all of the child detail panels render for every patient in the list.  How do I just have the child 'patient' detail show/render for the clicked parent?  Would it be better to use an action vs. #link-to?

Answer (score 0):

Your {{outlet}} is inside the each loop which means that you will have as many outlets on your page as there are patients... Try

```
{{#each item in model}}
    {{#link-to "patient" item}}show detail{{/link-to}}
{{/each}}
{{outlet}} <--where "patient" detail panel goes
```